# Why the place of synchronized() matters?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning Thread Safe. I wrote an example and got a question.

First, my main() function is the same:

```
public class ThreadSafe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Thread Safe");

        SafeSharedRunnable r = new SafeSharedRunnable();

        // Access the same resource
        Thread tA = new Thread(r);
        Thread tB = new Thread(r);
        Thread tC = new Thread(r);
        Thread tD = new Thread(r);

        tA.start();
        tB.start();
        tC.start();
        tD.start();
    }
}
```

Then I have two versions Runnable in which synchronized() are placed in different places, and thus, one version works and one doesn't.

The working version:

```
public class SafeSharedRunnable implements Runnable {
    int count = 5;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Thread Safe, must be outside of while(), why?
        synchronized ("") {
            while (count > 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }
                System.out.println("Current value is: " + count--);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

The correct result:

```
run:
Thread Safe
Current value is: 5
Current value is: 4
Current value is: 3
Current value is: 2
Current value is: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The non-working version:

```
public class SafeSharedRunnable implements Runnable {
    int count = 5;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (count > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }
            // Thread Safe
            synchronized ("") {
                System.out.println("Current value is: " + count--);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

The wrong result:

```
run:
Thread Safe
Current value is: 5
Current value is: 4
Current value is: 2
Current value is: 3
Current value is: 1
Current value is: 0
Current value is: -1
Current value is: -2
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

As you can see, different places of different synchronized() blocks result in different results. In my understanding, the key resource conflict should happen on this line of code:

```
System.out.println("Current value is: " + count--);
```

But why I must place synchronized() outside of while() block? Does that mean I should synchronize all the codes that contains variable "count"? Thanks for your detailed explanation.

I don't think this is a duplicate to race condition question, because I am not asking any general knowledge about multi-threading. Instead this is a detailed question about how multi threads enter a code flow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition)

Comment: `synchronized ("")` - this does work because Java deplolys `String` interning for `String` constants. But you should really use a dedicated `lock`-object instead, possibly `this`. And the placement of `synchronized` does matter because it defines which statement(s) are executed exclusively.

Comment: synchronized (""): don't, ever, do that. You really don't want several unrelated tasks to interfere with each other because they synchronize on a global empty string.

Comment: Why does the place of any line of code matter?

Comment: `I should synchronize all the codes that contains variable "count"?` if you want those operation to be thread safe, yes.

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation of the "Non-Working Version"

If the `synchronized` only wraps the `System.out.println`, then you're only guaranteeing the print statements to happen one at a time. So all of the threads could entire the `while` immediately at the beginning of the run, before anything has been decremented. Once all the threads are inside the `while` loop, they will run the print and decrement regardless of the `count`.

### Explanation of the "Working Version"

However, if you wrap the `while (count > 0) {` in the `synchronized` as well, then **only one thread can enter the `while` at a time**. This means **each thread must check the count before performing the entire contents of the while loop**, including the decrement.

Comment: Thank you, I think you explain it well.

Comment: It should be mentioned that all console output in the working version is produces by only one thread.

Comment: Note: `System.out.println` is synchronized so it doesn't make much difference to write it with synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is

```
// if four threads come here and now count is 1
synchronized ("") {
    System.out.println("Current value is: " + count--);
}
```

The four threads will print `count` in turn that caused the output `1 0 -1 -2`.

Try this code

```
synchronized("") {
    if (count > 0) {
        System.out.println("Current value is: " + count--);
    }
}
```

Although your working version got the right output, you synchronized the while loop which means there is only one thread doing the whole things. This is not what a multithreading should do.

Comment: I think in your last words you propose a very good view to think about this problem and multi-thread programming. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you put  `synchronized ("")`  inside while block then multiple thread same time see count =1 and all will enter inside while loop and decrease count and resulting wrong result.If you make count atomicinteger then it will be visible to all thread.